# Title in navigation bar in tableview ios

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I read and tried many solutions from stack to set a title to my navigation bar item but no one works. My navigation bar is in a table view.

I tried (in init,in viewDidLoad, in viewWillAppear) :

```
self.title = @"Title for TabBarItem";
```

and

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title for NavigationBar";
```

It's not working.
Can someone explain me why it's not working? What's the solution?

Comment: navigation bar inside the tableview ? explain ?

Comment: I use a navigation bar in the top of my tableview to add navigation button. My navigation buttons works.

Comment: SO your root view controller is a navigation controller ? You have a view controller with a tableview in it?

Comment: I have a view controller with a button.
When i click on the button, my app loads an uitableviewcontroller with my navbar inside my tableview.

Comment: Why is the navbar inside the tableview ?

Comment: because it's a navbar for my tableview only!!!!

Comment: I can't apply a background color to my navigation bar too.

Comment: Well self.navigationItem isn't going to work as the View Controller isn't inside the navigation controller. For some reason you've added a navigation controller to a tableView so it's now a subView of the table view. However you've created the navigation controller just reference that when you want to change it ?

Comment: I don't have navigation controller; I use storyboard id and segue. I put a navigation bar into my table view because my tableview is linking to an other tableview, and my navigation bar control the navigation between them.

Comment: The view controller which contains the tableview should be inside a navigation controller. I don't use Storyboard/Segues so I don't know how you've set this up.